# Is there any way to make the cut command read the last field only?

Tags: command-line, cut-command

I have a space seperated string which is output by a command, which I like to pipe to `cut`, using `-fd ' '` to split on spaces. I know I can use `-f <n>` to display field number `<n>`, but can I make it display the last field if I don't know the length of the string?

Or do I need to use a more flexible text editing tool like `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: I think cut command cannot support, but not sure, did you have a try with cut -d' ' -f-  ?

Comment: More ways of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727107/how-to-find-the-last-field-using-cut-linux

Comment: @KasiyA `-n` makes it the n from the start, `n-` is from n to the end, and there is the `--complement` option which reverses the selection. But no way to count the number of fields and act upon it as far as I can tell.

Comment: This would make a nice extension to any cut program

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No `cut` can't do that. You could use two `rev` commands, like

```
echo 'foo bar baz' | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

but it's usually easier to use `awk`:

```
echo 'foo bar baz' | awk '{print $(NF)}'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using only shell, no external tool is needed, using Parameter Expansion:

```
${var##* }
```

`var##*` will discard everything from start up to last space from parameter (variable) `var`.

If the delimiter can be any whitespace e.g. space or tab, use character class `[:blank:]`:

```
${var##*[[:blank:]]}
```

**Example:**

```
$ var='foo bar spam egg'

$ echo "${var##* }"
egg


$ var=$'foo\tbar\tspam\tegg'

$ echo "$var"
foo    bar    spam    egg

$ echo "${var##*[[:blank:]]}"
egg
```

Comment: I'd spoken about using parameter expansion in a comment on Severus Tux's answer, but the blank character class is useful information, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I personally like Florian Diesch answer. But there is this way too.

```
a=$(echo "your string here" | wc -w)
echo "your string here" | cut -d' ' -f$a
```

Explanation:

`wc -w` gives the number of words. and `cut` cuts the last word

EDIT:

I figured another way of Doing it:

```
echo "Any random string here" | tac -s' ' | head -1
```

Comment: Correct, but this is true when delim is space or tab, and if your cut delim is not same, this will fail

Comment: Nice lateral thinking, though if I'm setting `a="my string here"` I could use parameter expansion of `${a##* }` too.

Comment: Yes, but the OP said he had a space separated string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one using `grep`

```
$ echo "Change is Good" | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
Good
```

#### How it works:

- grep with `-o` Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line.
- The regexp `[^ ]*$` matches anything from end until it found a space.

---

Another one liner from [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17073/52402) using perl

```
$ echo "Change is Good" | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]'
Good
```